# do I need two useEffect for mount and state change?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose you want to fetchData on mount and when a variable `nonApproved` changes.
Do I need two useEffect or only one?

```
   useEffect(() => {
     fetchData()
   }, [])

   useEffect(() => {
     fetchData()
   }, [nonApproved])
```

Comment: If you intend to fetch the data even when the `nonApproved` gets changes then you don't need `two useEffects`. But if you wish to do some other operations when `nonApproved` gets changed but want to fetch only once then you need two.

Comment: I feel all answers will have a mistake in them because it depends on the type of variable `nonApproved`, is it a state? If it's a global variable it just won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 useEffect is enough.

Below runs both on mount as well as when `nonApproved` value is changed.

```js
useEffect(() => {
     fetchData()
   }, [nonApproved])
```

Answer (score 1):

The second one covers the first one, it will be triggered after component mounted (initial render) and when ever `nonApproved` changed  you only need:

```
useEffect(() => {
 fetchData()
}, [nonApproved])
```